# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0 when running in container dotnet core container

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, json.net, nuget

On macOS. This issue seems to be caused by Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.

This is my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>devopsapp_gke</RootNamespace>
    <!-- Add these BindingRedirects settings makes no difference -->
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Storage.V1" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.6.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The code is just doing this:

```cs
var storage = StorageClient.Create();
foreach (var bucketobj in storage.ListObjects("mybucket", "")) { }
```

Looking in `myapp.deps.json` I see the ONLY version of Newtonsoft.Json in any dependency is 12.0.3

Locally I can run `dotnet run -p ./myapp/myapp.csproj` without issue. Ran `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` and run again and it still works.

I try to launch this in a Docker container and I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer..ctor()
   at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer..cctor()
```

Pulled Dockerfile right from official docs:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY . ./

RUN dotnet nuget add source "https://myrepo" --name mysource --username "myuser" -p "mypass" --store-password-in-clear-text
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Running the container I get this:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer..ctor()
   at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer..cctor()
```

What is happening? I can exec into the container and confirm the Newtonsoft dll is there.

### Edit

I left this out because I didn't think it was related but I found removing my own nuget source solves the problem- but I need to add that source to get my custom packages.

The `RUN dotnet restore` works after running nuget add source  and even `dotnet restore --no-cache --force` runs without error. but I get that runtime error.

Why is my private nuget source causing this issue? Restore succeeds and I see the DLL. The private nuget source is an Artifactory repo mirroring microsoft repos. Shouldn't it just fail if it can't find the right package?

Comment: You could sidestep the entire problem by using the JSON functionality built into .netcore 3+.  I know this doesn't answer your problem but might be the path of least resistance.

Comment: i cant. the library im using depends on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>` to your .csproj?

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
   ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

It helped me with a similar problem, when I got those errors running a Docker container, but not when debugging from VS on Mac.

[Cred to Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx)